# Update input and image with JQUERY AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

first sorry for my english.
I have a news system. I can create, and delete news but i have a problem with the update.

When I click in 'Editar Noticia' (Edit new), I receive dynamically my new with the id(hidden), image saved(hidden), image new(empty), title, description short and description complete 
**Image saved = the image that I have uploaded at the beginning when I created the news.**

I think this is OK, but I leave the code here of this part.

```
elseif ($accion == 'editarNoticias'){

$id = $_POST['id'];

//Consulta BD Editar Noticia segun el ID.
$statement2 = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE idNoticia = $id");
$statement2->execute();
$noticias = $statement2->fetchAll();

//MODIFICAR DESDE ACA
echo "<h1 class='text-center m-5'>Editar noticias SB</h1>
<form id='formEditarNoticia' class='text-center' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";

foreach ($noticias as $noticia) {
echo "<div class='form-group mt-5'>
<input type='text' value='" . $noticia['idNoticia'] . "' id='idNoticia' >
<input type='text' id='imagenNoticia-guardada' value='" . $noticia['imagenNoticia'] . "'>
<input type='file' class='form-control-file mx-auto' id='imagenNoticia' id=' placeholder=' aria-describedby='fileHelpId'>
<small id='fileHelpId' class='form-text text-muted text-center'>Seleccione la imagen que quiere subir...</small></div>

<div class='col mx-auto mb-3'>
    <input id='tituloNoticia' type='text' class='form-control' value='" . $noticia['tituloNoticia'] . "'>
</div>

<div class='col mx-auto mb-3'>
<input id='noticiaCorta' type='text' class='form-control' value='" . $noticia['noticiaCorta'] . "'>
</div>

<div class='col mb-3'>
    <textarea id='noticiaCompleta' rows='20' cols='50' type='text' class='form-control'>" 
    . $noticia['noticiaCompleta'] . "</textarea>
</div>

<div class='d-inline-block'>
    <button class='enviarEditarNoticia btn btn-success'>EDITAR NOTICIA</button>
    <a href='index.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>VOLVER</button></a>
</div>
</form>";
}

}
```

So, I modify the inputs and i select a new image.
Then, when I click the button EDITAR NOTICIA (Edit News), this button have a class .enviarEditarNoticia, I do the next code with JQUERY AJAX:

```
        $("#seccionEditarNoticia").on("click", ".enviarEditarNoticia", function() 
     {
        $('#formEditarNoticia').serialize();
        id = $('#formEditarNoticia input').attr('value');
        var formData = new FormData($("#formEditarNoticia")[2]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "subirNoticia.php?p=modificar",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(info) {
                $('#mensaje').empty();
                $('#mensaje').append(info);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**and i think there, is the problem. I don't know how can I send my modified input values to my PHP** subirNoticia.php?p=modificar. Here the code:

```
elseif ($accion == 'modificar') {

    $idNoticia = $_POST['idNoticia'];
    $imagenNoticia_guardada = $_POST['imagenNoticia-guardada'];
    $imagenNoticia = $_FILES['imagenNoticia'];
    $tituloNoticia = $_POST['tituloNoticia'];
    $noticiaCorta = $_POST['noticiaCorta'];
    $noticiaCompleta = $_POST['noticiaCompleta'];


    if (empty($imagenNoticia['name'])) {
        $imagenNoticia = $imagenNoticia_guardada;
    } else {
        $carpeta_destino = '../img/noticias/';
        $archivo_subido = $carpeta_destino . $_FILES['imagenNoticia']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagenNoticia']['tmp_name'], $archivo_subido);
        $imagenNoticia = $_FILES['imagenNoticia']['name'];
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE noticias SET tituloNoticia = :tituloNoticia, noticiaCorta = :noticiaCorta, noticiaCompleta = :noticiaCompleta, imagenNoticia = :imagenNoticia WHERE idNoticia = $idNoticia"
    );

    $statement->execute(array(
        ':tituloNoticia' => $tituloNoticia,
        ':noticiaCorta' => $noticiaCorta,
        ':noticiaCompleta' => $noticiaCompleta,
        ':imagenNoticia' => $imagenNoticia
    ));

    echo "La noticia ha sido editada correctamente.";

  }
```

I tried a lot of things, I could insert and delete but i can't update because i don't know how can I send my new values. In Insert and Delete I use **data:** to send the ID, but here I can't because I have a **formData**

Other of my problems was that i write in the inputs, but with firebug i have seen and the value of the input don't change.

I do not know what else to do. Hope someone can help me.
Again sorry for my english and thanks for your time.

Comment: you are repeating ID attributes ( certainly `imagenNoticia-guardada` possibly others ) within the loop - every element must either have a unique ID or none, using the same ID is incorrect. Several form elements also have no `name` attribute which would hinder regular form submission.

Comment: @RamRaiden thanks for reply. I don't understand which is the problem, the loop is only for show 1 news (for edit), so there are one ID different for each input. Sorry if I don't understand correctly. And thanks again